# TCP server does not return a message to the client

Tags: python, server, tcp, client

This is the client:

```
from socket import *
server_IP_address = '127.0.0.1'
server_Port = 60000
server_socket_address = (server_IP_address, server_Port)
socket_del_cliente = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
socket_del_cliente.connect(server_socket_address)
mensaje_tx = input ('Introduzca su mensaje en minÃºsculas: ')
socket_del_cliente.sendto(mensaje_tx.encode(), server_socket_address)
print('mensaje enviado')
mensaje_rx= conexionSocket.recv(2048)
print('Recibido del servidor: ', mensaje_rx.decode())
socket_del_cliente.close()
```

And this is the server:

```
from socket import *
server_Port = 60000
socket_del_servidor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
socket_del_servidor.bind(('', server_Port))
socket_del_servidor.listen(5)
conexionSocket, clientAddress1= socket_del_servidor.accept()
print('Servidor preparado para recibir')
print(clientAddress1)
mensaje_tx, clientAddress2 = conexionSocket.recvfrom(2048) #responder a la misma direccion desde la que se ha enviado
print(clientAddress2)
print('Buen mensaje', mensaje_tx.decode())
mensaje_rx = input('Introduce una respuesta: ')
socket_del_servidor.sendto(mensaje_rx.encode(), clientAddress1)
print('Mensaje enviado', mensaje_rx)
socket_del_server.close()
```

if i run both the server and the client, the client is able to send a message to the server but the server is not able to send a message back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple example that you can use

server :

```
from socket import *

server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

server.bind(("",6000))
server.listen(5)

while True:
    connection,address = server.accept()
    msg=connection.recv(1024)
    print(msg.decode())
    connection.send("Thank you".encode())
    connection.close()
```

client :

```
from socket import * 

so = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

so.connect(("127.0.0.1",6000))

so.send("hello server".encode())
print(so.recv(1024).decode())
so.close()
```

output :

[image]

Your mistake was that the server was not constantly waiting for the message